# Setting up nvim on termux

Tags: neovim, termux

I have installed nvim succesfully with apt install. However when I open it, the following error is displayed (hitting enter a few times opens neovim succesfuly with the regular vim motions working as intended).

I think I saw some suggested fix somewhere online, but it suggested editing[image] files that was unable to locate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem to this. The init.lua and init.vim files both configure the settings in neovim. I'm not entirely sure, but it could be, as shown in the error message, that the two files cancel each other out. The solution I suggest is to choose one of the two configuration files, or see this Reddit post if you need both: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/zfimqo/is_it_possible_to_use_initvim_and_initlua_together/

Comment: Sorry about the notification I found no other way of contacting you, I have the solution for your wsl font problem but the question got closed on me while writing. Where can I write you?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your effort, I appreciate it. You can write to me on Discord. My Discord name is: d_guy_, I'm still looking for the ID.